# PhpStorm - navigation back keyboard shortcut not working

Tags: php, phpstorm

When I <kbd>Ctrl + click</kbd> on method it will jump to declaration of that method.

**Question: How to jump back to usage of that method?**

I tried <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Left</kbd> combination but nothing happen (not working).

When I click `Navigation > Back` it worked.

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/navigation-in-source-code.html

> Back
>   [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Left]
>   Undo last navigation operation.
>   On a OS X computer, you can also use the three-finger right-to-left swipe gesture.

Comment: Possibly this shortcut is used by your OS/desktop manager for another purposes. Either disable such shortcut on system level .. or change shortcut for `Navigate | Back` action to any other that works for you at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behaviour | Keymap`.

Comment: I just tried and I have the same problem. I'm on Ubuntu. I tried to rebind the keys in settings -> keymap, but couldn't bind anything with arrows. Don't know if the problem comes from PHPStorm or from the OS. Try to rebind the keys with something else than arrows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On windows <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>[direction]</kbd> will rotate display (if video card supports it). You have to change this shortcut to something else (mine is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>[direction]</kbd>).
`Settings` / `Appearence & Behavior` / `Keymap` / `Main menu` / `Navigate` / `Left`

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/279756/how-to-disable-the-screen-orientation-hotkeys-in-windows-xp - removing the screen rotation hotkey (which is IMHO such a rarely used feature that a global hotkey is total overkill) also fixes the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Following is a screenshot on ubuntu. Switch to workspace Left/Right need to be edited to use that shortcut on PhpStorm

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because of  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>   Keyboard Shortcuts is already set for another program.In my ubuntu this shortcut is for change worspace

You need to set your custom shortcut from Settings / Appearance & Behavior / Keymap /

And search navigate then change your back command