# PhpStorm back navigation broken on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpstorm

I have had issues in the past where the PhpStorm shortcut for jumping back a step (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + [direction key]</kbd>) wasn't working. And each time, I'd follow the [following issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345421/phpstorm-navigation-back-keyboard-shortcut-not-working/30345718) and remove the Linux shortcut key which was conflicting with PhpStorm.

However, I recently upgraded to Linux 20.04. I reviewed the Linux keyboard shortcut list over and over and can not find one which has this conflicting shortcut key!

To add more confusion, when I looked at my shortcut list in PhpStorm, under the shortcut listing for "Main Menu -> Navigate -> Back/Forward", it listed <kbd>Alt + Shift + Left/Right</kbd>. When I tried to add <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right</kbd>, it didn't actually let me add it!

Any help is welcome.

[image]

Comment: They `Settings | Keymap` screen has a button next to the local search field -- it allows to see what actions are mapped to the entered shortcut. Please use it to see if the IDE recognizes those `Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right` shortcuts at all. Right now it sounds like your OS is handling that shortcut and not allowing to pass further down to the app.

Comment: Yes, I know. Thats the issue. The problem is, when look at my Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts, I don't see CTRL + ALT + [direction key] listed. So I"m wondering if there might be a different place to look... See my screenshot

Comment: If this is "where to find that shortcut in Ubuntu" or "what this shortcut does in Ubuntu and how to change it" then please try https://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50373094/783119 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50921761/783119 as well.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for that second link, that did it! Can you post an answer and I'll approve?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what exactly you did .. plus the last 2 links I gave seem to be talking about the same ... so you better post your own answer with exact steps that worked for you (you can accept own answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Ubuntu 18.04 conflict with Intellij back/forward navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50717546/ubuntu-18-04-conflict-with-intellij-back-forward-navigation/50921761#50921761), I did the following and it fixed the issue.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['']"
```

I still am super confused, because I don't see any Workspace Left or Workspace Right entries in my keyboard shortcut settings.... but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on elementaryOS 5 and in my case was work this recipe

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "['']"
```

And now in **PHPSTORM** shortcuts `Crtl + Alt + Shift + Up & Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Down` are working!

Based on [user1015214's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68697250/).

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).

Comment: @cigien this is merely repeating [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68697250/4826457) now..